# Keep scroll in mobile web

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a responsive webpage, and it will auto refresh after 5 second, to keep the page still at the last scroll position before refresh I use localStorage to store the value of the scroll position, It work very nice when I access from computer, but when I take it on the phone, the web page can not move back the the last scroll position. Anybody have any idea for it ? How can I keep the scroll position in mobile web?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('scroll_top', document.body.scrollTop);
        $('#show').load("detaildata.php", function(){
            if (localStorage.getItem('scroll_top') !== null)
                window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem('scroll_top')));
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What phone are you using? iOS? Android?

Comment: Also did you try to test and see if your actually storing the number on page reload? Maybe attach it to the document after reload and see if you are storing the value. This way we can narrow down the possible problems.

Comment: I'd recommend to not refresh the page

Comment: I use Google Chrome on Android device :( There is no way to do this ? My page have to refresh because the data is always update every 5 seconds

Comment: I just found a problem because in mobile web cannot get the value of document.body.scrollTop it alway return 0, I will try to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem, some browser is support document.documentElement.scrollTop, some browser support document.body.scrollTop to get the scroll position, even it is Google Chrome in desktop and Google Chrome in mobile. It better that we check both of it, and get which different with 0.